# Twitter Bootstrap Anchor not clicking

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

i'm making a navbar with dropdown in twitter bootstrap. For some reason the anchors inside the dropdown aren't working. 
this is my nav code:

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
                {{ navigation:links group="header" }}
                {{ if user:logged_in }}
                     <li class="dropdown">
                     <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">{{user:first_name}}  <b class="caret"></b></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="{{url:base}}profile/{{user:id}}"><i class="icon-user"></i>Profiel</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-inbox"></i>Berichten</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-cog"></i>Instellingen</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="{{url:site uri='users/logout'}}" tabindex="-1">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    {{ if user:group == "admin" }}
                        <li style="position:relative">
                            <a href="{{url:base}}admin"><i class="icon-wrench icon-white"></i></a>

                            <!--
                            <a href="{{url:base}}admin">
                                <img src="{{url:base}}assets/img/gear.png" style="width:20px; height:20px; margin-bottom:4px;" />
                            </a>
                            -->
                        </li>
                    {{ endif }}
                {{else}}
                    <li><a class="login-link" data-role="button" data-toggle="modal" href="#login">Login</a></li>
                {{ endif }}
            </ul>
```

Does anybody know why this can be? For now the only the profile anchor and the logout anchor are filled in, but both of them aren't doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is another layer which is overlapping your logout link.
You need post more HTML code and CSS for everyone can debug this

Comment: No, i think it has something to do with a e.preventdefault, but i'm not doing anything like this...

Comment: In HTML page, your below code look like? <a href="{{url:base}}profile/{{user:id}}"> . And I think, you may post the whole HTML page which everyone can review some related elements which cause your problem.